# set outputCommitterClass property in hadoop2

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

I have been researching this problem for the past few weeks, and didn't find a clear answer.

Here is my problem:

For hadoop1x (in `mapred` lib), we could use customized output committer by using:

```
spark.conf.set(
  "spark.hadoop.mapred.output.committer.class",
  "some committer"
 )
```

or simply calling `JobConf.setOutputCommitter`.

However, for hadoop2x (in mapreduce lib), it gets the committer from `OutputFormat.getOutputCommitter`, but there is no clear answer on how to `setOutputCommitter`.

I found databricks set the output committer by using this property,  `spark.hadoop.spark.sql.sources.outputCommitterClass`.

I tried it with netflix's s3 committer(`com.netflix.bdp.s3.S3DirectoryOutputCommitter`), but in the log, spark still uses default committer:

```
17/09/13 22:39:36 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
17/09/13 22:39:36 INFO DirectFileOutputCommitter: Nothing to clean up since no temporary files were written.
17/09/13 22:39:36 INFO CSEMultipartUploadOutputStream: close closed:false s3://xxxx/testtable3/.hive-staging_hive_2017-09-13_22-39-34_140_3769635956945982238-1/-ext-10000/_SUCCESS
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to overwrite default `FileOutputCommitter` and use my customized committer in `mapreduce` lib?

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily no; it's something I'm trying to fix [MAPREDUCE-6823](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6823) -where you'll be able to set a committer per filesystem schema. That won't surface for a while (Hadoop 3.1?)

You should be able to get away with setting the sql output committer, though I'd check the path. That probably only kicks in for SQL/dataframe work. You can also set it for Parquet separately, though the committer you declare must be a subclass of ParquetOutputCommitter, which the netflix one isn't.

Comment: I'm able to make parquet format work since it uses separate logic of retrieving committer, but I'm not able to set the sql output committer for non-parquet format.

Comment: Hi there - what configuration do you need to set on the cluster for this to work @baryonX?